# Write a Plug-in for Cloud foundry authentication

Tags: cloud-foundry

I need to integrate the Cloudfoundry with third party authentication tool, say, Keystone. I need to write a plug-in where it can be attached / installed to the cloud foundry with out any code changes in Cloudfoundry. If I want to use the authentication from keystone I will install the plug-in for Cloudfoundry. The code changes should only go to the plug-in and not to the Cloudfoundry code.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance,
Sateesh B.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Keystone, but you may have to integrate with the UAA component: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa
Also, if your question is regarding the OSS project, you may have better luck asking on the Google Group: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/vcap-dev/topics

Answer (score 1):

The following link https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client is a java client library that does restful calls to vcap (aka cloud foundry). Now in my opinion, if you want to use a custom authentication method (be whatever you choose) in high level terms, you would have to make it into a adapter design pattern.

Once your users pass your authentication, your application can then communicate with Cloud Foundry via rest calls or libraries such as https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client and have their account created or etc. You just have to add that layer of your own authentication which then you can use the data from the authenticated user in creating or fetching cloud foundry info/apps.

This way you haven't touched cloud foundry and you can easily implement more than one way of authentication.